# specialized static crashing ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
import Foundation
import K

@objc class KU: NSObject {

static func setUpConfigs() {
    let productId = TNYEnvironment.sharedInstance().kProductID
    let url = TNYEnvironment.sharedInstance().kUrl
    K.sharedInstance.configureK(productId,
                                               url: NSURL(string: url)!)
}

static func trackEvent(eventName: String) {
    let formattedEventName = eventName.lowercaseString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "_")
    self.trackEvent(formattedEventName, properties:[:])
}

static func trackEvent(eventName: String, properties: [String: NSObject]) {
    let instance = K.sharedInstance
    instance.track(eventName, params:properties)
    instance.uploadEvents({})
 }
}
```

Its crashing on ipa build, but works fine on debugger. I guess some issue with swift to objc code. Anyone had the same issue?

Comment: What logs or errors does it give you?

Comment: @keithbhunter 0x245b48 specialized static KU.setUpConfigs() -> () (KaleidoscopeUtils.swift:19)